# Customize bootloader splash screen for non x86 targets

Tags: windows-ce, splash-screen, platform-builder

I'm building an OS in Windows CE 6.0R3 targeted for the ARM9 architecture (Specifically it's for the iMX28 series) and I'd like to change the boot screen to display a custom image when the device is first booted up.

How can I do this? I read through some rather [vague and sparse bits of documentation](http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2009/07/12/platform-builder-creating-a-cepc-splash-screen.aspx) that suggest you need to create it in the .bmx format and enable video, but nowhere do I see how to actually *change* the splash screen shown when the device is booted up.

Comment: Flag for SU. Just because it deals with creating an OS, does not mean it is for SO

Comment: @ColeJohnson: I disagree. The scope of SU seems to be towards `computer enthusiasts, power users` according to their FAQ. This really isn't either situation.

Comment: Agreed, this is a development question - specifically about OS/Platform development - and is fair game for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.  Generally speaking it's the bootloader that controls initialization of the display controller and sending data to the controller for the initial image that appears before the OS is loaded and it's display driver takes over.  In a typical **x86** target device using the out-of-the-box BIOS bootloader that ships with Platform Builder, it will load the splash.bmx (a compressed BMP) and display that.

In all ARM-based cases I'm aware of, BIOS bootloader is **not** what is used to load the image, but instead is a BSP or vendor-specific loadr.  I've seen a variety of things from custom OEM bootloaders to derivatives of redboot.  In those cases, you have to know how the bootloader is set up to display a splash image and how to configure it (if you even can - some are hard-coded).

Since we don't know what bootloader you're using, I won't even hazard a guess as to the specifics for how yours works.  Your best bet is to either check with your platform documentation and see if it's described, or check with the OEM.  If you happen to be the OEM, you'll have to look into the source code for whatever bootloader you are using.

Comment: Thanks. That actually helps significantly point me towards where to go. We already have already (slightly) modified the bootloader that's included in the BSP.

Comment: Look at the frame buffer initialization area.  Typically it gets painted in right after that.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into what ctacke recommended, I found that for the `iMX28-eVK-PDK1_9` BSP that was used in my OS project I needed to modify the code within `display.c`.

Specifically, it was found within the platform project under `iMX28-EVK-PDK1_9\SRC\BOOTLOADER\COMMON\display.c`. The function `ShowBmp` was used to load the bitmap from a fixed in memory location. I had to adjust the code for `ShowBmp` to instead write the desired bitmap to the screen instead of the default Freescale image.

By default, `ShowBmp` reads from a memory location a bitmap image and writes it pixel by pixel to the device screen. The only thing we really changed was that we were reading from our memory location instead.